# React Native App and a UnStable Internet Connection

Tags: android, ios, react-native, database-connection

I have an React Native app that relies heavily on an internet connection.

The app has questionnaire functionality (which works fine).
But there is one functionality where the user is supposed to upload an audio-recording, here the app freezes and won't start working again.

I am in need of solutions for how my android app can keep a good user experience with an unstable internet connection! (Most errors happens in Android)
How can I achieve this??

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Add a listener for internet state change in your HomeScreen, And navigate it to a separate screen, whenever there is No internet connection. You can use this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo - for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

check the network connection available or not, on based on the condition the user will show the UI so there will no collapse
use library like

- @react-native-community/netinfo
- react-native-network-info
  https://reactnative.directory/?search=network&order=relevance